# Find if the limit $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}+\frac{z}{\bar z}$ exists or not

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

My try:
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}+\frac{z}{\bar z}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2-y^2-2ixy}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{x^2-y^2+2ixy}{x^2+y^2}$$
so
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}+\frac{z}{\bar z}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$
doesn't exist indeed

- for $y=0$ $$\implies \frac{2(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{2x^2}{x^2}=2\implies \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}+\frac{ z}{\bar z}=2$$
- for $x=0$ $$\implies \frac{2(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{-2y^2}{y^2}=-2\implies \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{z}+\frac{ z}{\bar z}=-2$$

so the limit doesn't exist indeed?

Comment: Your conclusion is right, but the computations could be simplified. When $z$ is real, $\bar z=z$, so $\frac{\bar z} z + \frac z{\bar z} =2$, whereas when $z$ is purely imaginary, $\bar z=-z$, so $\frac{\bar z} z + \frac z{\bar z} =-2.$

Comment: if you use $z=re^{i\theta}$, your expression is 
$$\lim_{r\to 0}(e^{-2i\theta}+ e^{2i\theta} )$$ which can take on any (real) value in $[-2, 2]$